# CodeIgniter can not access global variable in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have already tried lots of ways. add library, add config file, add a controller, just add in same controller.........etc.
This also have same problem:
(this is add in same controller)

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller{
  public $data = array();

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    //if call add_data() here, it is work
  }

  function add_data(){
    $arraya = array('a'=>'aa', 'b'=>'bb');
    $this->data = $arraya;
  }

  function index(){
    $this->add_data();
  }

  function want_print(){
    print_r($this->data);
  }
}
?>
```

if I call add_data in index, i cannot get any data in want_print()....
if I call add_data in the construct, i can get data in want_print()..

Please anyone help me solve this problem?
I don't want to call it in construct because i will not call it every time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the data in your `want_print()` function like this:

```
function want_print() {
    $this->index();
    print_r($this->data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it will console the html in console...can have some way to dont display?

Comment: just remove the print_r() statement if you don't want to display the data.

Comment: no，it print the html from this->index, i dont want print this in console

Comment: you can call the add_data() function instead of index() in your want_print() function. replace $this->index() with $this->add_data() inside your want_print() function.